# Why isnt my collision detection working for Enemies vs playerOne

Tags: javascript, css, html, object

I am building a simple game where the user controls the blue square and the goal is to enter the red box. The enemy squares I made are not detecting the playerOne object. Im not sure why and the other questions that have been answered are not really helping. I fear its something specific to my code. Theres probably a million things I have done wrong as well. 
Hope you can help! Thank you.

Here's all of my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Javascript Testing</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color:darkblue;
            }
            #page {
                background-color: skyblue; border: 5px solid orange;
                height: 650px;
                width: 600px;
                margin:auto;
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
            }
            #main {
                background-color: white; border: 5px solid black;
                margin: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
            }
        </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="page">
   <h1>javascript testing</h1>
   <canvas id="main" width=500, height=500></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>
  // Canvas Work
   var can = document.getElementById("main");
   var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
   
   // Variables
        var startPlat = new Platform(can.width/4, can.height-50, 250, 50, "#11eeaa");
        var endPlat = new Platform(can.width/3, 0, 150, 50, "#ff5555");
  var playerOne = new Player(can.width/2, can.height-30, 30, 30);
  var Enemies = [];
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            Enemies[i] = new Enemy(Math.floor(Math.random()*300), Math.floor(100+Math.random()*300), 30, 30);
  }
  
  // User Controls
  var leftPressed = false;
  var rightPressed = false;
        var upPressed = false;
        var downPressed = false;
  
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
  
  function keyDownHandler(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 39){
          rightPressed = true;
      } else if(e.keyCode == 37){
          leftPressed = true;
      }else if(e.keyCode == 38){
                upPressed = true;
            }else if(e.keyCode == 40){
                downPressed = true;
            }
  }
  function keyUpHandler(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 39){
          rightPressed = false;
      } else if(e.keyCode == 37){
          leftPressed = false;
      }else if(e.keyCode == 38){
                upPressed = false;
            }else if(e.keyCode == 40){
                downPressed = false;
            }
  }
            
        // Collision Detection
        function CollisionDetection(){
            if(playerOne.y + playerOne.height < endPlat.y + endPlat.height-2 &&
               playerOne.x + playerOne.width < endPlat.x + endPlat.width && playerOne.x - playerOne.width > endPlat.x){
                window.alert("Success!")
                document.location.reload();
            }
            if(playerOne.x + playerOne.width < Enemies.x){
                window.alert("FAILURE!")
                document.location.reload();
            }
        }
  
  // Objects
  function Player(x, y, width, height){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.speedX = 0;
      this.speedY = 0;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.draw = function(){
          ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
          ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }
      this.move = function(){
                 if(leftPressed && this.x > 0){
                 this.x += -3;
                 }
                if(rightPressed && this.x < can.width - this.width){
                this.x += 3;
                }
                if(upPressed && this.y > 0){
                    this.y += -3
                }
                if(downPressed && this.y < can.height - this.height){
                    this.y += 3;
                }
      }
  }
  function Enemy(x, y, width, height){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedX = Math.floor(Math.random()*2+2);
    this.speedY = Math.floor(Math.random()*2+2);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = "red";
    this.draw = function(){
     ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
     ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.move = function(){
     this.x += this.speedX;
     this.y += this.speedY;
     if(this.x < 0 || this.x > can.width-this.width){
         this.speedX = -this.speedX;
     }
     if(this.y < 0 || this.y > can.height-this.height){
         this.speedY = -this.speedY;
     }
                 if(this.x + this.width > startPlat.x && this.x < startPlat.x + startPlat.width &&
                    this.y + this.height> startPlat.y && this.y < startPlat.y + startPlat.height){
                        this.speedY = -this.speedY;
                        this.speedX = -this.speedX;
                        
                 }
                 if(this.x + this.width > endPlat.x && this.x < endPlat.x + endPlat.width &&
                    this.y + this.height > endPlat.y && this.y < endPlat.y + endPlat.height){
                        this.speedY = -this.speedY;
                        this.speedX = -this.speedX;
                        
                 }
                    
    }
    
   }
        function Platform(x, y, width, height, color){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.color = color;
                this.draw = function(){
                    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
                }
            }
            
   //Draw Stuff Here
   animate = function(){
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);
             startPlat.draw();
             endPlat.draw();
          for(i = 0; i < Enemies.length; i++){
              Enemies[i].draw();
              Enemies[i].move();
          }
            playerOne.draw();
            playerOne.move();
            CollisionDetection();
             
            
   }
   animate();
   setInterval(animate,10);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your collision detection isn't working because you haven't got any code to do it. Add this inside your `CollisionDetection()` function:

```
Enemies.forEach(function(enemy) {
    if (enemy.y + enemy.height < playerOne.y && enemy.y + enemy.height > playerOne.y + playerOne.height && enemy.x + enemy.width < playerOne.x + playerOne.width && enemy.x - enemy.width > playerOne.x) {
        //Do stuff here
    }
})
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You're checking for collision with `Enemies.x`, but `Enemies` is an array, and `Enemies.x` is `undefined`. Loop through them and check for collision like your success box collision detection.

Comment: @Joundill I am - that's the purpose of `enemy`.

Comment: That's the reason I upvoted your answer :) My comment was meant to be directed at the asker

Comment: @JackBashford Thank you so much for your quick help. the forEach method is a new one for me that I will begin to practice. But unfortunately I am still flying right through the red squares with no alert. Is the "enemy" parameter supposed to be capitalized because my object constructor is?